# how to filter filenames started by `assets` in TortoiseHg

Tags: tortoisehg

In commit console, how can I filter all files started by `assets`? so `assets/*` will filtered and `protected/assets/*` will not.

I tried `^assets` which filtered all files.

[image: Filter text in TortoiseHg]

Answer (score 0):

how about `^assets/*` ? That will tell Mercurial to ignore anything under `assets` but to track files under `nbproject/protected/assets` or `protected/assets`. Your screenshot suggests that Mercurial has been tracking files under `assets` before; if you don't want Mercurial to track them anymore, but want to keep your local copies, run `hg forget`